# What is the difference between a 500W high pressure mercury lamp and a 400W high pressure mercury lamp

Tags: photochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

I know that the Wattage of a UV lamp is only one factor in the UV output of a light, and therefore cannot be used as a measure of how powerful a light is. Also it doesnt have any effect on the produced wavelength. Is it like this that a lamp with higher wattage can cause higher temperature on substrates that are being irradiated ?

Comment: My guess is that a higher wattage would create a wave with a higher amplitude

Comment: Only that one is brighter than the other but probably with a bigger focussed spot size which may necessarily not give a larger number of photons/area. (A low pressure Hg lamp is far less intense and just at one wavelength)

Comment: Generally speaking, the wattage rating on devices simply tells you how much power it will draw. Whether or not it will put that power to good use is dependent on the design. I would agree with Bob and say that you'll get the same wavelength from both lamps but the 500 W lamp is likely to give you higher amplitude light.

Comment: I don't like the wording "higher amplitude light." A 500 watt light and a 400 watt light would probably have very similar wavelength distributions. At every wavelength of the spectral output the 500 watt light would have 5/4 the intensity (photons per second) of the 400 watt light.

Comment: The difference between the two is $\pu{100W}$ …

Answer (score 1):

I would say all other things being equal, i. e. Spectral distribution,  quantum efficiency,  that more wattage = more photons per second. And yes, more heat.

Comment: Exactly. The difference is: 100W.